# gnutls_handshake() failed

Tags: ubuntu, gnutls

A few months ago I was able to snipe actions on ebay with esniper. Today I get the following when I use it:

> Auction 12345678901234: Cannot connect to URL https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn: SSL connect error: gnutls_handshake() failed: Illegal parameter
>       Retrying...

I already have the latest version installed. How can I solve this?

(Ubuntu Linux 14.04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to replace `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` with `libcurl4-openssl-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

(this will deinstall the `gnutls` library).

After that extract the sources from the installation tarball, change into the directory and run the usual:

```
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

that worked for me (ref [this bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/esniper/bugs/695/))